# Google Sheets API batch update updateChartSpec does not update right axis viewWindowMax

Tags: google-sheets-api

What I really want is a combo chart where right axis and left axis have the same viewWindowMax which is the one that will let all the data in the chart.
For this, I try to get the highest of the 2 and set both of them to that max.

batchUpdate of a chart in google sheets requires to update the whole chart["spec"] with updateChartSpec. I have test cases where I set viewWindowMax to a hardcoded arbitrary number. It updates properly the left axis, but the left axis goes back to a default condition with an empty viewWindowOptions even if it did have some other value before the update. IE I get this result with no error message:

{'position': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {'viewWindowMin': 0, 'viewWindowMax': 40, 'viewWindowMode': 'PRETTY'}}, {'position': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {}}

when in the request it was like so:

{'position': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {'viewWindowMin': 0, 'viewWindowMax': 40, 'viewWindowMode': 'PRETTY'}}, {'position': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {'viewWindowMin': 0, 'viewWindowMax': 40}}

removing the 'PRETTY' thing or adding it changes nothing.

Full request code looks like this:

```
requests = [
    {
        "updateChartSpec": {
            "chartId": chart['chartId'],
            "spec": spec
        }
    }
]
body = {
    'requests': requests
}
response = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds.credentials).spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

with spec variable =

```
{'title': 'Tickets Opened and Closed', 'basicChart': {'chartType': 'COMBO', 'legendPosition': 'BOTTOM_LEGEND', 'axis': [{'position': 'BOTTOM_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {}}, {'position': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {'viewWindowMin': 0, 'viewWindowMax': 40, 'viewWindowMode': 'PRETTY'}}, {'position': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'viewWindowOptions': {'viewWindowMin': 0, 'viewWindowMax': 40}}], 'domains': [{'domain': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 0, 'endColumnIndex': 1}]}}}], 'series': [{'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 1, 'endColumnIndex': 2}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 1}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 1}}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 2, 'endColumnIndex': 3}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 1, 'green': 0.42745098, 'blue': 0.003921569}, 'colorStyle': {'themeColor': 'ACCENT5'}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 3, 'endColumnIndex': 4}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 0.9764706, 'green': 0.79607844, 'blue': 0.6117647}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 0.9764706, 'green': 0.79607844, 'blue': 0.6117647}}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 4, 'endColumnIndex': 5}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN'}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 5, 'endColumnIndex': 6}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 1}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 1}}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 6, 'endColumnIndex': 7}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 1, 'green': 0.42745098, 'blue': 0.003921569}, 'colorStyle': {'themeColor': 'ACCENT5'}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 7, 'endColumnIndex': 8}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 0.9764706, 'green': 0.79607844, 'blue': 0.6117647}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 0.9764706, 'green': 0.79607844, 'blue': 0.6117647}}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 8, 'endColumnIndex': 9}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'RIGHT_AXIS', 'type': 'COLUMN', 'color': {'red': 0.20392157, 'green': 0.65882355, 'blue': 0.3254902}, 'colorStyle': {'themeColor': 'ACCENT4'}}, {'series': {'sourceRange': {'sources': [{'sheetId': 1666134379, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 14, 'startColumnIndex': 9, 'endColumnIndex': 10}]}}, 'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS', 'type': 'LINE', 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'themeColor': 'TEXT'}}], 'headerCount': 1, 'stackedType': 'STACKED'}, 'hiddenDimensionStrategy': 'SKIP_HIDDEN_ROWS_AND_COLUMNS', 'titleTextFormat': {'fontFamily': 'Roboto'}, 'fontName': 'Roboto'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to report this behavior here: https://issuetracker.google.com/151918491

Comment: thanks @Allesanro, I was going to do it after a day or 2